# How to fix "Cannot read property 'react' of undefined" in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api, discord.js

I'm setting up a discord bot with reactions, but there is an error in the second reaction by number, but I can not find it. It's probably a loop error, but I've already tried to change the names of variables, nothing helps. I am also sorry for the length of the code, but I have tried to shorten it to the maximum.

After hitting command `!bot`, the bot should reply with a message with 5 possible reactions.
If I press *reaction 1*, a second message appears with the description, the discord and the date in an embed.
At the bottom of this message should appear a reaction ✅.
Everything works without worries except that nothing happens when I press this reaction.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!bot')) {

    async function accessSpreadsheet(embed) {
      const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1qA11t460-ceILmwu6RtfiPGb_n9MUD_7z6Ld7I_Z6yc');
      await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
      const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
      var sheet = info.worksheets[0];

      var cells = await promisify(sheet.getCells)({
        'min-row': 2,
        'max-row': 7,
        'min-col': 16,
        'max-col': 16,
        'return-empty': true,
      })
      for (var cell of cells) {

      }
      for (let i = 0; i < 25 && cells[i]; i++) {
        {
          if (i == 0) embed.addField('Name', `•1⃣ ${cells[i].value}`, false);
        } {
          if (i == 1) embed.addField('Name', `•2⃣ ${cells[i].value}`, false);
        } {
          if (i == 2) embed.addField('Name', `•3⃣ ${cells[i].value}`, false);
        } {
          if (i == 3) embed.addField('Name', `•4⃣ ${cells[i].value}`, false);
        } {
          if (i == 4) embed.addField('Name', `•5⃣ ${cells[i].value}`, false);
        }
      }
    }

    var embed = new RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setTitle("A title");

    try {
      var sentMessage = await accessSpreadsheet(embed)
        .then(() => message.author.send(embed))
        .catch(console.error);

      for (let n = 1; n <= 5; n++) await sentMessage.react(`${n}⃣`);

      const filter = (reaction, user) => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].includes(reaction.emoji.name.slice(0, 1)) && user.id === message.author.id;
      const collected = await sentMessage.awaitReactions(filter, {
        maxMatches: 1,
        time: 4000
      });

      if (collected.size === 0) {
        await message.channel.send('Time ran out');
      } else {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        switch (reaction.emoji.name.slice(0, 1)) {
          case '1':
            async function accessSpreadsheet(embed1) {
              const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1qA11t460-ceILmwu6RtfiPGb_n9MUD_7z6Ld7I_Z6yc');
              await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
              const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
              var sheet = info.worksheets[0];

              var cells = await promisify(sheet.getCells)({
                'min-row': 2,
                'max-row': 7,
                'min-col': 16,
                'max-col': 16,
                'return-empty': true,
              })
              for (let i = 0; i < 25 && cells[i]; i++) {
                {
                  if (i == 0) embed1.setTitle(`You select: ${cells[i].value}`);
                }
              }
              var cells1 = await promisify(sheet.getCells)({
                'min-row': 2,
                'max-row': 7,
                'min-col': 17,
                'max-col': 17,
                'return-empty': true,
              })
              for (let j = 0; j < 25 && cells1[j]; j++) {
                {
                  if (j == 0) embed1.setDescription(`Description: \n \n ${cells1[j].value}`);
                }
              }
              var cells1 = await promisify(sheet.getCells)({
                'min-row': 2,
                'max-row': 7,
                'min-col': 18,
                'max-col': 18,
                'return-empty': true,
              })
              for (let l = 0; l < 25 && cells1[l]; l++) {
                {
                  if (l == 0) embed1.addField(`Discord:`, `${cells1[l].value}`, true);
                }
              }
              var cells1 = await promisify(sheet.getCells)({
                'min-row': 2,
                'max-row': 7,
                'min-col': 20,
                'max-col': 20,
                'return-empty': true,
              })
              for (let k = 0; k < 25 && cells1[k]; k++) {
                {
                  if (k == 0) embed1.addField(`Date:`, `${cells1[k].value}`, true);
                }
              }
              for (let k = 0; k < 25 && cells1[k]; k++) {
                {
                  if (k == 0) embed1.addField(`To be validated with ✅:`, `click on reaction`);
                }
              }
            }

            var embed1 = new RichEmbed()
              .setColor('#0099ff');
            await accessSpreadsheet(embed1)
              .then(() => message.author.send(embed1))
              .then(message => {
                message.react('✅')
                //Problem starts here

                client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
                  if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && user.id !== client.user.id) {
                    async function accessSpreadsheet(embed2) {
                      var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1qA11t460-ceILmwu6RtfiPGb_n9MUD_7z6Ld7I_Z6yc');
                      await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
                      var info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
                      var sheet = info.worksheets[0];
                      var cells = await promisify(sheet.getCells)({
                        'min-row': 2,
                        'max-row': 7,
                        'min-col': 21,
                        'max-col': 21,
                        'return-empty': true,
                      })
                      for (let m = 0; m < 25 && cells[m]; m++) {

                        {
                          if (m == 0) embed2.addField(`Days before toornament: ${cells[m].value}`, `Choose options: \n 1⃣  \n 2⃣ \n 3⃣ \n \n **(5 sec)**`);
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    var embed2 = new RichEmbed()
                      .setColor('#0099ff');
                    try {
                      var sentMessage1 = await accessSpreadsheet(embed2)
                        .then(() => message.author.send(embed2))
                        .catch(console.error);

                      for (let z = 1; z <= 3; z++) await sentMessage1.react(`${z}⃣`); // The error is here

                      const filter = (reaction, user) => ['1', '2', '3'].includes(reaction.emoji.name.slice(0, 1)) && user.id === message.author.id;
                      const collected = await sentMessage1.awaitReactions(filter, {
                        maxMatches: 1,
                        time: 4000
                      });

                      if (collected.size === 0) {
                        await message.channel.send('Time ran out');
                      } else {
                        const reaction = collected.first();

                        switch (reaction.emoji.name.slice(0, 1)) {
                          case '1':
                            message.channel.send('1')
                            break;
                          case '2':
                            await message.channel.send('You chose `two`.');
                            break;
                          case '3':
                            await message.channel.send('You chose `3`.');
                            break;
                        }
                      }
                    } catch (err) {
                      console.error(err);
                    }

                  }
                })
              })

              .catch(console.error);
            break;
          case '2':
            await message.channel.send('You chose `two`.');
            break;
          case '3':
            await message.channel.send('You chose `3`.');
            break;
          case '4':
            await message.channel.send('You chose `4`.');
            break;
          case '5':
            await message.channel.send('You chose `5`.');
            break;
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
})
```

I know this should only work with Reaction 1, but the console shows:

> **DiscordAPIError**: Can not send messages to this user
>   **TypeError**: Can not read property 'react' of undefined`

The error is raised on the following line:

```
for (let z = 1; z <= 3; z ++) await sentMessage1.react (`$ {z} ⃣`);
```

Comment: If you have an error, please provide the line of the error. We can guess that the error is on a line when you try to eact to something, but there isn't only one, reading your whole code to understand what line could have a problem is harder than just one line. Can you also explain what your bot is supposed to do? Don't paste the whole code, paste the part that has a problem.  read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [make a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes of course. The bot should, after the command !bot, reply with a message with 5 possible reactions. If I press reaction 1, a second message appears with the description, the discord and the date in an embed. At the bottom of this message should have a reaction ✅. Until everything works without worries. The problem is that if I press this reaction, nothing happens.

Comment: In the console.log, there is the error: "DiscordAPIError: Can not send messages to this user" followed by "TypeError: Can not read property 'react' of undefined" to the line ```for (let z = 1; z <= 3; z ++) await sentMessage1.react (`$ {z} ⃣`);```.

PS: I put all the code, because if I take the first part and the second separately, all the code works

Comment: I edited your post (which is waiting to be peer reviewed). So you know, there is an edit function on all post. You can edit your post without restriction, to add clarification when people ask for example, instead of adding it in comment (comment aren't supposed to be necessary to understand the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you are using async/wait but handling it like a promise.then

```
var sentMessage1 = await accessSpreadsheet(embed2)
                        .then(() => message.author.send(embed2))
                        .catch(console.error);
```

`sentMessage1` does not receive anything back from you call.

You either must return a something that has `.react` on it or handle everything inside your then statement.

```
var sentMessage1 = await accessSpreadsheet(embed2)
                        .then(() => {
                             message.author.send(embed2);
                             message.author.react(####); //I don't know the discord API
                         })
                        .catch(console.error);
```