# Detecting when someone reacts to a bot-created message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So the goal is to give a user the option to recover their deleted message by sending a message, reacting to that message with Y and N, and detecting when that same user reacts with Y.

I wrote out all the code, and it looks fine, but it seems the variable 'question' loses track of the message object originally stored in it because it throws `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: question.on is not a function`. I've tested

I know such a thing is possible because [Toasty](https://toastybot.com) relies on this often.

Disclaimer: I have `.then()` in my code, but I'm not entirely sure I'm using it right.  I've never used it before, but looking into it, it seemed right for the job.

Other Disclaimer: I saw [another post with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951757/how-to-fix-cannot-read-property-react-of-undefined-in-discord-js) on this site, but I honestly don't understand the answer, and I feel like this code is a more concise version of the issue.

```js
client.on('messageDelete', function(msg){
  if (msg.author.id == 42){ //I'll plug my discord account in a different post,tyvm
    msg.channel.send ("I saw that, FOOL");
    msg.channel.send ("Would you like me to bring your message back from the grave? (Y/N)").then (function (question){
      question.react("");
      question.react("");
      question.on('messageReactionAdd',function (reaction, author){
        if (reaction == "" && author.id == 42){
          msg.channel.send ("FOOL: " +msg.content);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So the `question` is the message object, it doesn't have`messageReactionAdd` listener, that is `clients` listener, it is used like this:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', function(msg){
    //code
})
```

What you really need is `awaitReaction` method on message object.

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' // or whatever
question.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 15000 })
  .then(col=>{
      console.log('reacted')
  })
```